# how to use enableFlutterDriverExtension() in main.dart with async function while testing flutter with flutter appium driver

Tags: flutter, appium

it gets error like

> unknown error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing
> the command. Original error: Cannot execute command get_text, server
> reponse {   "isError": true,   "response": "Uncaught extension error
> while executing get_text:
> 'package:flutter_driver/src/extension/extension.dart': Failed
> assertion: line 366 pos 14:
> 'WidgetsBinding.instance.isRootWidgetAttached ||
> !command.requiresRootWidgetAttached': No root widget is attached; have
> you remembered to call runApp()?\n#0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew
> (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)\n#1
> _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)\n#2      FlutterDriverExtension.call
> (package:flutter_driver/src/extension/extension.dart:366:14)\n#3
> BindingBase.registerServiceExtension.
> (package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart:855:32)\n\n",   "type": "_extensionType",   "method":
> "ext.flutter.driver" }

tried enableFlutterDriverExtension()  in async main with ensureflutter widgetbinding